# Android back soft key line of code in DialogInterface

Tags: android

How do I execute the back command inside a `DialogInterface.OnClickListner` positive button? I want to ask first the user if he/she wants to go back to the previous activity. I've tried `super.onBackPressed();` but it is not a valid code for this.
Here's my code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener confirm = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:{
                //execute back function
                super.onBackPressed();
                break;
            }
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:{
                //Do nothing, just stay on the current activity
            }

            }
        }
    };
    AlertDialog.Builder msgbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    msgbox.setMessage("Are you sure you want to go back?");
    msgbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", confirm);
    msgbox.setNegativeButton("No", confirm);
    msgbox.show();
}
```

the `super.onBackPressed();` is giving me this error prompt `The method onBackPressed() is undefined for the type object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've made changes to the code to reflect your needs. This should do.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener confirm = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:{
                //execute back function
                finish();
                break;
            }
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:{
                //Do nothing, just stay on the current activity
                break;
            }

            }
        }
    };
    AlertDialog.Builder msgbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    msgbox.setMessage("Are you sure you want to go back?");
    msgbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", confirm);
    msgbox.setNegativeButton("No", confirm);
    msgbox.show();
}
```

Comment: Am I still going to use `@Override public void onBackPressed(){}` on top of this code you've given? @tgo

Comment: no, remove `@Override public void onBackPressed(){}` and put the override I placed above

Comment: the code that handles my button click is in the `onBackPressed();` itself. where else can i put my `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`?

Comment: getActivity() is an error.. i've tried replacing it with `this.finish();` still an error.. how will i call the current activity properly?

Comment: it works now.. i've removed `getActivity()`... `finish();` will do the work.. thanks! ;)